# Problem when using Feeds to import nodes which have a image field

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I'm using feed to import nodes from a csv file. I'll try to reproduce.

**Everything works fine if I do this:**

1) I create the importer. For Mapping Settings I set:

```
ID -> Node ID
TITLE -> Title
BODY -> Body
```

*This importer will import the csv data to the **cuadros** content type*

2) I import this csv file with no problem at all:

```
ID;TITLE;BODY
83;without title;text
1084;White;text
```

**But I get a message error if I include a image for the node**

1) I create the importer. For Mapping Settings I set:

```
    ID -> Node ID
    TITLE -> Title
    BODY -> Body
    PHOTO -> Images
```

*Images is a image field of the node.*

2) I put the 2 images files in: `localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/photos/`

3) I import this csv file

```
ID;TITLE;BODY;PHOTO
83;without title;text;http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/photos/245c-w1000-h800.jpg
1084;White;text;http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/photos/261-w1000-h800.jpg
```

4)I get the error message you can see below.

Just in case it was a permission problem I set the **files** folder and all its content to 777, but problems stil persist

```
 The specified file temporary://filel1sCPA could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
The specified file temporary://fileqPBtxM could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.


Invalid enclosure http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/photos/245c-w1000-h800.jpg
Invalid enclosure http://localhost/mysite.com/sites/default/files/photos/261-w1000-h800.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was that I had to use the default folder for the image fied, which is **images**. I had set **photos** as the folder for the images.